# How to Bevel the vertical edge of a rectangle?

Tags: bevel

Am trying to remodel this : 
[image]

And thought the best way to start is the with the interior part of the head, and started with a cube and "bevel it", the top part went fine but the sides are giving me this weird rectangle effect :

[image]

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you haven't selected the angle edges from bottom to top

Comment: can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I thought you wanted to create a bevel from bottom to top. If you only want to create a bevel on a part of this angle, I guess Blender tries to find the best way to create a correct topology: If it didn't create a triangle it would create a vertice between the two top vertices and it wouldn't give a good topology, here I created a bevel, then tried to find a solution to delete the triangle, as you can see it's not good topology: https://zupimages.net/up/18/27/9x6p.jpg   but someone certainly knows better than me on this topic